# Rename [cocos2d] tag to [cocos2d-python]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

The [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag description states the following:

> It is recommended to use the following tags appropriately:
>
> - Use the [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) tag on questions referring to the Python
>     based framework
> - Use the [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) tag on questions
>     referring to the Objective-C based framework
> - Use the
>     [cocos2d-x](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) tag on questions referring to the C++ based
>     cross-platform framework
> - Use the [cocos2d-javascript](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-javascript) tag on
>     questions referring to the JavaScript based framework
> - Use the
>     [cocos2d-android](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-android) tag on questions referring to the Java based
>     frameworks
>
> **Don't use any of the above tags together** in the same
>   question, unless your question refers to more than one Cocos2D engine.
>   For example, if you ask "How to port from *Cocos2d for iPhone* to
>   cocos2d-x?" you should include both [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) and [cocos2d-x](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) tags.

Cocos2d was originally written for Python. However, the cocos2d-iphone subproject has gained more popularity than its parent.

Very few people are aware of this and most of users tag the [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone) questions as [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) because they think the iOS version is the original `cocos2d`.

Renaming [cocos2d](/questions/tagged/cocos2d) to [cocos2d-python](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-python) would help in avoiding this kind of mistagging.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the logic behind the name change, but you can't just rename it off the bat. The problem is that there are going to be a ton of questions tagged "cocos2d" that *don't* refer to the python framework--that's the exact point you're making, after all. So first you'd have to go through the 4,582 questions tagged "cocos2d" and retag the relevant questions to the proper sub-tag.

I have to admit I'd have thought the cocos2d tag would be for the iPhone version too, so I can see the logic behind changing this tag. But there's a log of work to be done retagging those questions before this is feasible. The first 10 questions tagged cocos2d all (at a glance) appear to be about cocos2d-iphone. So there's a lot of legwork here before this is feasible.

Comment: Yeah, that's an important thing to have in my mind, thanks for pointing it out. However, I'd say that the current situation is that the majority of [tag:cocos2d] tags are in reality [tag:cocos2d-iphone] or other (I'd be surprised if more than 10% were actually [tag:cocos2d-python] questions). So, maybe one could merge [tag:cocos2d] with [tag:cocos2d-iphone] instead (because [tag:cocos2d-python] already exists).

Comment: Another solution I can think of is: leave all cocos2d tags like they are, but change the [tag:cocos2d] tag description so it is a cross-platform general one (and keep a separate [tag:cocos2d-python] for [tag:cocos2d]'s current puprose). What it is clear in my mind is that trying to enforce the current [tag:cocos2d]-and-subtags policy is impossible, due to the reasons I stated above.